# Finding elements by data-toggle with jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a need to dynamically build a form using jQuery. This form has a checkbox list of items. I am building this list like this:

```
function initializeForm()
{
  var html = '';

  var items = GetItems();
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    html += '<div><input id="item' + item.ItemId + '" data-toggle="itemCheckBox" name="SelectedItemIds" value="' + item.ItemId + '" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;' + item.Name + '</div>'; 
  }
  $('#itemList').html(html);
}
```

I am trying to react to the user clicking one of the checkbox using the following:

```
$('input[data-toggle="itemCheckBox"]').change(function() {
  alert('here');
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert('check');
  } else {
    alert('uncheck');
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, this event handler never fires. I do not understand why. My selector looks correct to me. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the `initializeForm()` called on load ?

Comment: @Varun - Yes. The form is loading exactly as I want. It is only the event handler that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the event handler is not bound because the elements are added to the DOM after page load. This should do it:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[data-toggle="itemCheckBox"]', function() {
    alert('here');
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('check');
    } else {
        alert('uncheck');
    }
});
```

This is binding the event to a selector. http://api.jquery.com/on/